# Groovy geb.waiting class is not found

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, jar

I am using eclipse oxygen 4.7. I have added geb.core-1.1.1.jar, geb-spock-0.10.0.jar, and spock-core-1.1-groovy-2.4.jar to the path. 
I am getting the following error.

> geb.waiting.Wait cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

When I import

> geb.waiting

I see waiting as a package but when I add it I get,

> Groovy:unable to resolve class geb.waiting

I have changed the geb-core library to 1.1 and 1.0 but I still have the same problem.
Please what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use geb-0.93.0 jar. I had the same Problem and I found the class in that package